# Print node title in custom block module twig file

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I want to send node title and description into twig file. See my code

```
public function build() {

return [
'#theme' => 'block--maincontentlatestnews',
'#latest_news' => $this->read_latest_news(),
'#sample' => 'sample_txt',
'#attributes' => [],
];
}

function read_latest_news(){

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','article')->execute();
$nodes = entity_load_multiple('node', $nids);

return $nodes ;

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're creating a custom module, don't reinvent the wheel, you can achieve the same using Views. In addition, you have not declared your [#cache property](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays) in your render array; therefore, your block will never change, well unless if and when someone manually clears all caches.

Comment: Don't use a base hook `block--`, define a custom template with custom variables, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return array_map(function($node) {
  return $node->label();
}, $nodes);
```

or if you want links:

```
return array_map(function($node) {
  return $node->toLink()->toString();
}, $nodes);
```

Comment: Thank you., Is there any way to get body and image fields for send it into twig file?